# returned value is undefined in protractor

Tags: protractor

when i click a link in our angular page,it open's a new tab. In that I need to compare the heading and few texts. 
below are the my code snippets.

```
this.getSupportPageTitle = async function(){
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        await browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(async function(handles){
            await browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(async function(){
                console.log('focus switched to new Tab');
                var title = await actions.getElementText(element(supportPageDiscription),'check support page title');
                console.log('title : ' +title);
                return title;
            });
        });       
    };
```

and have a spec

```
it('Display Support Page',async function(){
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      var supportPageTitle = await manageSupportPage.getSupportPageTitle();
      if (await manageSupportPage.getSupportPageTitle()){
        console.log('true');
      }
      else{
        console.log('false');
      }
      console.log('Title from page :' +supportPageTitle);
      await expect(supportPageTitle).toEqual(expected_result.expectedSupportPageDiscription);
    });
```

In page, i can print the title.But when it returns to spec it saying undefind. Any help can be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you missed `return` for the function. And you can write your function body as `Sync programming` as following with using `async/await`:

```
this.getSupportPageTitle = async function(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    var handles = await browser.getAllWindowHandles();

    await browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
    console.log('focus switched to new Tab');

    var title = await actions.getElementText(element(supportPageDiscription),'check support page title');
    console.log('title : ' +title);

    return title;
};
```